# Filtering a data tree, building a new tree

Tags: c#, tree

Given a data tree class:

```
class DataTreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<DataTreeNode<T>> 
{
    public KeyValuePair<T, int> Data
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public DataTreeNode<T> Parent {get; set;}
    public ICollection<DataTreeNode<T>> Children {get; set;}
.....
}
```

The Data property contains a key for the data and a value for the data type.
and given a tree instance, I need to build a sub-tree filtered as follows:

a. contains only certain values of leaf nodes (Data.Key)

b. the path to the leaf conforms to:

1. contains only certain types of nodes (Data.value)
2. does not contain certain types of nodes (Data.value)

I tried extracting all possible paths as lists of nodes, filtering the lists and rebuilding a tree, but have not succeeded so far.

I feel intuitively that it should be done using some king of recursion, but I have no idea how to do the filtering and the construction of the new tree inside the recursion.

Comment: And what have u tried?  Need to see some code!

Comment: There are very many lines of code, which probably means its the wrong approach as this should be short and concise; they also don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution (not recursive):
Build a list of paths from root to each leaf.
Then build a new tree filtering each path as we go:

```
DataTreeNode<string> createFilteredTree(List<List<DataTreeNode<string>>> paths, List<int> types, List<bool> flags, string filter, string title)
    {
        DataTreeNode<string> root = new DataTreeNode<string> (new keyValuePair<string, int> ("SEARCH RESULTS", 0));
        foreach (List<DataTreeNode<string>> path in paths)
        {
            if (!passesFilter (path, types, flags, filter))
                continue;//don't need this path
            path.Reverse ();
            DataTreeNode<string> curNode = root;
            DataTreeNode<string> found;
            foreach (DataTreeNode<string> node in path)
            {
                found = curNode.FindTreeNode (node1 => node1.Data.Equals (node.Data));
                if (found == null)
                {
                    found = node.Clone ();
                    curNode.AddChild (found);
                }
                curNode = found;
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with *walking* the tree in a recursive function, probably printing the *path* at each node to see what is going on.

Then, instead of printing you apply your filter and *add* a new node to the result-tree with the contents of your current node.

Comment: The problem is the decision depends on more than one node: 
It depends on the end leaf AND on some of its parents; in addition, the new tree has to preserve the original tree's structure and hierarchy.

Comment: Still: find a way to evaluate your condition while you are at the current node.

Comment: Maybe the solution would be to 'prune' the tree, deleting all non-conforming leaves and branches.

Comment: Don't change a collection while you _walk_ over it

Comment: I can get a collection of all nodes conforming to some criteria and then delete them one by one without walking the tree; or can't I?

Comment: Just don't change the tree _while you walk the tree_